# VS Code – jump to current debugging position via keyboard

Tags: debugging, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, how do I jump to the current position of the debugger? It is indicated by a yellowish line, but I tend to get lost browsing other files and functions, only to struggle finding my way back to where my debugging session is currently paused at.

Should be simple enough, but I could not find anything in the docs. I even went through all actions containing 'debug' in the keyboard map, but did not find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### @updated answer for recent VSCode:

### `Navigate to Top of Call Stack`

In recent VSCode (1.71 +), there is a `Navigate to Top of Call Stack` command (`workbench.action.debug.callStackTop`). You can simply assign a shortcut to it in your keyboard shortcuts menu.

--> pointed out by [CoderBlue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73717524/2072165), please leave an upvote there :)

#### Original Answer for VSCode < 1.71:

The desired effect (jump to the current execution point) can be achieved by clicking on (or selecting with the keyboard) the topmost entry in the "Call Stack" view.

Using the [multi-command macro extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) (inspired by [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56266040/2072165)), a custom command can be created which will always select the topmost entry in the call stack view.

This goes to your `keybindings.json`:

```json
{
    "key": "cmd+f4",
    // Go to current debugging position
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "sequence": [
        "workbench.debug.action.focusCallStackView",
        "list.clear",
        "list.focusFirst",
        "list.select"
        // optional, to focus your editor:
        // workbench.files.action.focusOpenEditorsView
      ]
    }
},
```

Comment: I got `command 'extension.multiCommand.execute' not found`, so I probably have to look at Marks answer to add code to the `settings.json`.

Comment: @Timo just to be sure, have you installed the extension?

Comment: No need for this now with the latest VS Code version. See VonC's answer and mine - simply add a keyboard shortcut to top of call stack.

Comment: @CoderBlue thanks for pointing this out. I updated the answer to reflect the more up-to-date way 

Answer (score 8):

## Quickly Add Keyboard Shortcut to Jump to Current Debugging Position in VS Code

### Building on [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72947881), specifically using the current version of VS Code, 1.71.0:

1. Type `ctrl-k ctrl-s` to get to the Keyboard Shortcuts.
2. Type "callstack" in search box and find "Navigate to Top of Call Stack".
3. Set the key binding, e.g., I use `ctrl-r d`:

[image]

4. Try it out! Now when I type `ctrl-r d` I"m there!

Comment: Nice! That should work. Upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't appear to be any `go to current breakpoint` command, only previous and next commands.

However, I see this "bug" might be useful: see [repl evaluation causes editor to jump to current breakpoint](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/69504)!

So you could just focus the repl, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you will jump to your current breakpoint.  It does pollute your debug console with an `undefined` result but perhaps that is acceptable.

Or you could assign a keybinding to a macro that executes the focus command and clears the debug console in one go.  Using a macro extension of your choice - I am using [multi-command below](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) - this would go into your settings:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

 {
  "command": "multiCommand.gotoCurrentBreakpoint",
  // "interval": 350,
  "sequence": [

    "workbench.debug.action.focusRepl",
    "repl.action.acceptInput",

    // following command clears the debug console if you wish
    "workbench.debug.panel.action.clearReplAction"
  ]
 }
]
```

and some keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+/",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.gotoCurrentBreakpoint" },
},
```

[image: demo of returning to current breakpoint]

How long the underlying "bug" - if it is a bug - will be there to use .....?

Comment: Thank you so much for digging this deep! By reading through the bug ticket you linked, I actually stumbled upon a more straightforward solution to my problem, which was kind of obvious but I had not noticed until then (I'll post it as an answer). Thank you also for mentioning the macro extension – this will come in handy for sure!

Comment: With `Alt+/` vscode first checks keybindings and then settings regarding the sequence? Why not put all code in keybindings?

Comment: @Timo At the time of the answer multi-command did not support using only a keybinding with all the commands.  That is a recent update to the extension.

Answer (score 2):

> The desired effect (jump to the current execution point) can be achieved by clicking on (or selecting with the keyboard) the topmost entry in the "Call Stack" view.

The "selecting with the keyboard" is now implemented with VSCode 1.70 (July 2022) and [issue 149975](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149975) ("Add keybinding commands to navigate the call stack while debugging (without needing a mouse)")

See [PR 154117](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/154117) and [commit 3d3bfce](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/3d3bfced969d0ffd1fdc7a1938cc26bbd64d9d42):

> ### Commands for Navigating Call Stack"
>
> Adds commands to navigate call stack.
> Users can manually add keybindings for this.
>
> Introduces the new commands (available when debugging is stopped):
>
> - `Debug: Navigate to Top of Call Stack`
> - `Debug: Navigate to Bottom of Call Stack`
> - `Debug: Navigate Up Call Stack`
> - `Debug: Navigate Down Call Stack`

you can therefore easily associate a key shortcut to "Navigate to Top of Call Stack", which is "where my debugging session is currently paused at".

This is available today in [VSCode insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

Answer (score 0):

"^" + "-" takes you to the previous position for mac users in editor, I don't know if it is same for debug window